# can not use logback binding for slf4j on jboss5.1.1

Tags: jboss5.x, slf4j, logback

My application has slf4j logging it should use logback binding, when I try to run on jboss it uses default binding for slf4j in jboss. It throws multiple binding error as it finds logback and jboss binding both. Also I am using slf4j1.7.2 with logback 1.0.9 but I receives error saying SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The step by step guide is at:
http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2010/04/eclipse-logback-plugin-with-jboss-as.html

The key is to have a class-loader isolation defined in your jboss-web.xml (assuming it is for web app)
Other links that may be helpful (I have to put the links as text as I'm not allowed to put more than 2 links in a post)

- http://blog.frankel.ch/configuring-maven-to-use-slf4j
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/junit-logback-maven-with-spring-3.html

If you are using Maven please remember:

- you have to make sure your libraries are not pulling older versions of slf4j by their dependencies, declare it directly if needed
- you do not have log4j in your WEB-INF/lib, if some of your libraries depend on log4j or commons-logging declare relevant bridges (see links above or http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL)